# JPA: Remove Child Entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, openjpa

I have an entity(ex: Document) that is used as child in 4 other entities(using @OneToMany with @JoinTable in parents). I am not using Bidirectional Mapping. My requirement is to remove the Child(i.e Document), and I have two ways to do that, one way is, get the 4 parents, remove child from them and update them. Second, using native query(using jdbcTemplate) to remove entry from 4 join tables and remove the child.

Is there any other way it can be done in much simpler manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an abstract base class containing the Document as member and user JPA inhertiance --> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance
Than it should be possible to get all users of a document with just one query.
Than it should be relatively easy to remove all references.

Don't do magic behind automatic deletion stuff. Thats for the cost of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Add orphan deletion (ie. delete child object when it's removed from collection in the parent). To enable it, you need to add

> @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)

in owning entity.

Comment: Yogesh, This is same as First option that I mentioned. With this I have to pull all the 4 parents which is costly DB transaction.

Comment: Yogesh, I have uni-directional mapping, and I am not deleting parent. I just want to delete child using its PK.